# Mutt checking incoming mail in tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux, mutt, bell

I've been using mutt and liking it. I work with tmux, and one issue that I've had is receiving notifications of incoming emails (via mutt's `beep_new` setting). I've got the `mail_check` and `timeout` variables set correctly, and they do the right thing. If I stay on the pane I'm running mutt in, it will check for incoming mail every 15 seconds. However, if I change to a different pane, mutt quits doing this. Just as a test, I've run this while in a different pane: `send-keys -t 4 'j'` to just "move the cursor" (or the selection or whatever) in mutt. This does cause mutt to get new emails, and the bell is activated, and the tab changes colors to notify me. How can I get mutt to check for email without me running `send-keys`?

Answer (score 1):

I think that I have figured it out. The bell doesn't trigger if I've already got another piece of mail open in mutt. I have to make sure I hit `i` before leaving the tab.